# Pyramid/Python security scanner?

Tags: python, security, pyramid

Is there an automated security scanner of any sort for [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about)?

I've seen these for other frameworks, like [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org) for Rails.  It would be really great if there was one for Pyramid (or even Python in general).

Then again, it wouldn't surprise me if there wasn't, because it's not quite as popular as Rails.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if Pyramid or any Python application is very good target for a security scanner. I am reading [this list](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/) and I am not sure if any of these issues are very applicable to Python web applications. It is interesting idea though.

Frameworks, like Pyramid, should have safe defaults so that OWASP top 10 most common vulnerabilities should not be happening in the first place.

- Usage of SQLALchemy or Django ORM prevents SQL injections
- Template engines do safe HTML escape by default
- Unsafe serialization (Python pickling) is non-existent as most code uses JSON
- I have not seen anybody doing `eval()` in Python, though this doesn't mean some poor soul somewhere would not be doing it
- etc.

However novice programmers surely can shoot themselves to foot with these kind of issues and it would make sense to catch handcoded SQL strings or `eval()` usage by an automatic scanner. But my gut feeling as being working with various Python web projects and security for over a decade is that in Python world the state of the matters is more robust and gains using a security scanner would be very small or non-existent.

Comment: You could make those exact same statement about Rails, too :) People still turn off defaults, bypass protections, and write unsafe code.

Comment: ORMs are great, but I've yet to see a non-trivial program that never needed to bypass it and use a raw SQL query at least once.  Template engines need a way to pass through trusted HTML, which may not be.  And so on.

Comment: Besides, security scanners aren't there to yell at you if you are perfect and always follow best practices.  They're there to catch when you don't.